# How to use a different path name in ProxyPass than the Tomcat context name

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy

I am using Tomcat 5.5.9 and Apache 2.x

We are trying to use a path name in ProxyPass that is different
than the Tomcat context name.

```
ProxyPass /path http://localhost:8080/contextname
```

However, this does not work. When these two are the same
then everything works fine.

Most examples I see on the net also have the path equal to
the Tomcat context name.

I am using "context.xml" within the Tomcat context and do
NOT have "server.xml" entries. Also, I am using plain
httd.conf and NOT using any VirtualHost entries.

Comment: Hint for debugging: Use [mod_dumpio](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dumpio.html) to dump the data going back and forth over the connections.

Answer (score 12):

I believe you need both

```
ProxyPass /path/ http://localhost:8080/contextname/
ProxyPassReverse /path/ http://localhost:8080/contextname/
```

Any reason not to use [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/)?

Comment: Hello David,

I did have both the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse commands even though I did not mention it in my message.

As for why not use mod_jk I simply need to hide tomcat port from user access URL and nothing else so mod-proxy seems the simplest

Comment: Fixed the solution - you probably must have the slashes at the end of the URI. This is copied from my conf files.

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/path$ /path/ [R]
RewriteRule ^/path/(.*) /contextname/$1 [P]

ProxyPass /contextname/ protocol://192.168.15.48:8080/contextname/
ProxyPassReverse /contextname/ protocol://192.168.15.48:8080/contextname/
```

Where "protocol"="http" in this case...

Comment: An alternative to using [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is to use [ProxyPassMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch). Could not get it to work properly in any case, very fragile, and then it occurred to me that I could just adjust the proxied application so that the URL paths on the left and right hand would correspond...

Answer (score 3):

Add a slash to both values:

`ProxyPass /path/ http://localhost:8080/contextname/`

Comment: Could you explain how this differs from no-trainlish-slash version?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem are probably self-referential URLs that the application produces. There isn't much you can do about it except for

1. changing the app or
2. rewrite everything that it spits out.

Option 2 can be very fragile. 
See [the tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/proxy.html) for more info.